# How do I access a helper method when I am running a test in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing a test for my email service, inside my email template file I call a helper method called: `do_it`, which is defined inside `application_helper.rb`

However, when i run my tests they fail because the helper methods are not imported, I get the following exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `do_it'
```

Any idea / suggestions on how i can import helper methods into tests?

I am using:

```
require 'test_helper'

class NotifierTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
```

Comment: But what is the class that is calling the do_it helper method? As I said below, you can include ApplicationHelper into that class using `SomeClass.send(:include, ApplicationHelper)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Helper is just a module containing instance level methods. RSpec gives you a way to access this by default in the Helper specs that are automatically generated, by using `helper.x` within the `describe` block for the helper. If you're not using RSpec, there may be some other method provided by your test framework. Alternatively, you can mix the module into a class and test on an instance of the class.

Somewhere in the test setup:

```
class ApplicationHelperTest; include ApplicationHelper; end
@helper = ApplicationHelperTest.new
```

And in your test:

```
assert @helper.do_it
```

To better address your exact issue, what you need to do then is include the helper in the class that the method is being called on. For example, let's say the class is Mailer:

```
Mailer.send(:include, ApplicationHelper)
```